# Submit a model in Mongoose that contains an array with ObjectID's

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have an object called `company` that inside I have `name(String)` and `locations(Array)`
Inside locations I want to have a key called `name` that the user will generate, and second key generated by using `ObjectID`.
Unfortunately I can't get this to work as expected.

[Example from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5F32.png). Note that the locations didn't get `_id`.

What is going wrong?

**My model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const companySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  locations: [
    {
      _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      name: String
    }
  ]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema)
```

**My controller**

```
  createCompany: (req, res) => {
    const { name, locations } = req.body

    const company = new Company({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: name,
      locations: locations
    })

    company
      .save()
      .then(() => {
        res.status(200).json({
          company
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({
          error
        })
      })
  },
```

Comment: Please use that schema const companySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  locations: [
    {
      name: String
    }
  ]
})

Comment: Why? I want to set _id for each location. I need it to be part of the schema as far as I know..

Comment: Beacuse automatically id defined in collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose will create `_id` for the top level and nested array of documents itself, which is a default behaviour.

So defining schema with only the fields that you want should be it.

```
const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  locations: [
    {
      name: String
    }
  ]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Company", companySchema);
```

**OR**

```
const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});
const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  locations: [locationSchema]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Company", companySchema);
```

And subsequently you don't need to create the `_id` from the Model object as well.

```
const company = new Company({
  name: name,
  locations: locations
});
company
  .save()
  .then(() => {})
  .catch(e => {});
```